# At the beginning of 2022, what are our site's biggest challenges?

Tags: discussion

Our "Cardano" site caters to a diverse set of users.

I believe that this is causing some unusual challenges and would like to hear what others feel are our biggest challenges and how we might address them.

Please add 1 answer per challenge and use the comments to offer your opinion on them.

Answer (score 1):

**Voting**

- Up-votes for answers and questions are both low.
- People not voting for a question unless they want to know the answer?
- Need to encourage people to vote for any new decent quality question?

Answer (score 1):

**Answers not being accepted**

- People are putting effort into answers and often not getting feedback
- Posters often don't mark an answer as accepted despite getting multiple answers

Answer (score 0):

**Plutus Pioneers**

- Appears to be a lot of new users unfamiliar with Stack Exchange
- Understandably more focused on Plutus Pioneers than providing quality questions and answers here
- Lots of transient questions (relevant to a specific cohort)